# django-restframework. How to change many to many field name in the serializer?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I know it is relatively simple to change a represented filed name in the serializer with `source` argument like this:

```
class SomeSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    alternate_name = serializers.SomeField(source='field_name')

    class Meta:
        fields = ('alternate_name')
```

But when dealing with a many to many field, the `source` is a `ManyRelatedManager` and using `source` in it leads to errors:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    field_name = models.ManyToManyField(OtherModel, related_name='groups')

class SomeModelSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    alternate_name = models.ListField(source='field_name')

    class Meta:
        fields = ('alternate_name')
```

This gives `ManyRelatedManager object is not iterable!`
Using other Fields instead of `ListField` gives other errors. What is the right approach here?

Comment: you need to use the nested serializer with many=True for this one https://django-rest-framework.narkive.com/Vae8fnWD/listfield-in-serializer-giving-manyrelatedmanager-object-is-not-iterable-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `obj.field_name.filter()` to get the related data and return this from `SerializerMethodField()` as stated above.

This is how I would do it not sure if it works for you.

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):

        field_name = models.ManyToManyField(OtherModel, related_name='groups')

class SomeModelSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    #name this field whatever you want
    some_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    # SerializerMethodField gets populated from "get_{filed_name}" method
    def get_some_name(self, obj):

        #this will return a list
        return obj.field_name.filter()

    
    class Meta:
        fields = ('some_name')
```